# How to insert Telugu text in input text box

Tags: add-on, development

I have made an addon with a input text box. I need to add text on Telugu language. But it appears as boxes in input field. Whne I see system tab under User preferences, in the interational font section, Telugu is not listed. How to solve this?

Comment: You need a font file capable of displaying telugo character glyphs,though not sure how you can use it in Blender UI

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos tried adding font. but it didnt work

Comment: What font did you use?